# Updating pandas dataframe with new column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column with all the distinct values across the rows. Each value in a row is a string(not list).

This is how dataframe looks like:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|         first               |            second       |           third                             |  
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|['able', 'shovel', 'door']   |['shovel raised']        |['shovel raised', 'raised', 'door', 'shovel']|
|['grade control']            |['grade']                |['grade']                                    |
|['light telling', 'love']    |['would love', 'closed'] |['closed', 'light']                          |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

This is how the dataframe should look like after creating a new column with distinct values.

```html
df = pd.DataFrame({'first': "['able', 'shovel', 'door']" , 'second': "['shovel raised']", 'third': "['shovel raised', 'raised', 'door', 'shovel']", "Distinct_set": "['able', 'shovel', 'door', 'shovel raised', 'raised']" }, index = [0])
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code to produce the data so  that people can directly copy and use. Also, can you please provide more details.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about what you are trying to achieve? and code you have tried would also aid that endeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['first'] + x['second']+x['third'])), axis =1)
```

its creating set of single char as your data in cell is string.

"['able', 'shovel', 'door']"

to correct this use below:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(eval(x['first']) + eval(x['second'])+eval(x['third']))), axis =1)
```

Comment: It is creating a set of each alphabet and punctuations whereas  I need set of words in an inverted comma.

Comment: @Mohit Sharma, avoid using eval, they have very destructive outputs. Check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[['able', 'shovel', 'door'], ['shovel raised'], ['shovel raised', 'raised', 'door', 'shovel']], [['grade control'], ['grade'], ['grade']], [['light telling', 'love'], ['would love', 'closed'], ['closed', 'light']]], columns=['first', 'second', 'third'])

df.apply(lambda row: [np.unique(np.hstack(row))], raw=True, axis=1)
```

The last command produces:

```
0        [[able, door, raised, shovel, shovel raised]]
1                             [[grade, grade control]]
2    [[closed, light, light telling, love, would lo...
```

which can be saved in a new column of the dataframe:

```
df['Distinct_set'] = df.apply(lambda row: [np.unique(np.hstack(row))], raw=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: You missed conversion of the list as a string value. Read the question again.

Comment: The brackets in the example from the main question are misleading, ie. are they supposed to be the part of the actual string? Once the author provides the code to generate the dataframe I will reassess.

Comment: He mentioned in the question, "Each value in a row is a string(not list)" if you see the first column from expected df also you will get to know.

Comment: OK, you are right. This means that the square brackets are the part of the strings, which is weird...

Answer (score 0):

You can try out below snippet

```
import json
def get_list_from_str(s):
    return json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))

def flatten_list_rows(row):
    return (set(
        get_list_from_str(row['first']) + 
        get_list_from_str(row['second']) + 
        get_list_from_str(row['third']) 
    ))

df['Distinct_set'] = df.apply(flatten_list_rows, axis=1)
```